# How do I keep files synchronized with Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: sync, cloud-storage, amazon-cloud-drive

I want to begin using Amazon Cloud Drive unlimited, but there is no synchronization available. Using [Cloud Drive Desktop](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201601260) there is only an upload. I do not want to keep uploading 1500 gigabytes repeatedly. They discontinued [Cloud Drive Sync Application](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201376690) (formerly called the "Cloud Drive desktop application"). Though it can be found and will still work I won't use unsupported software.

I regularly back up my machines to a terabyte drive and when finished I clone that drive to another. I want to begin synchronizing in the cloud. I have a few folders I back up in between full backups and would like to keep those synchronized, too.

The terabyte drive has a lot of old files, archives, and historical stuff as well.

Comment: Just as an aside: Amazon UK still serves the old pages and downloads for the original [Cloud Drive desktop application](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200957230).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get the free dropbox or box.net account. I dumped the amazon synch app a while ago. It was terrible at actually synching and the worst part is that is sneaks up on you. One day, bam - nothing but CONFLICT files.

Comment: Since asking this question I received a reply from Amazon saying there is no synchronization available. If the same folder is uploaded again, warning messages appear for any files or folders already present, so there is no way to refresh except to delete and upload the whole thing again.

Comment: I may try dropbox. I wanted to do Amazon because it's better on the backend and they support value-added services by others well, but it's lousy on the front end.

Comment: I don't mind Amazon having a limit of 2TB or 4TB, but unlimited and then no sync app?  My money will go to DropBox, OneDrive, Copy, or Google Drive instead, or even my own RAID drive mirrored, or a personal NAS Cloud

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An excellent solution became available for Amazon Cloud Drive that works wonderfully! The interface to Amazon Cloud Drive, provided by Amazon, leaves much to be desired. There is a web interface and PC application, neither of which work very well except to do a one-time placement onto the server.

SyncBackPro recently implemented an Amazon Cloud Drive interface. This is different from their Amazon S3 and Amazon Glacier interfaces. I can't believe how well it works. It is a bit slow initiating upload on a file by file basis, but once it begins processing a file it goes at the limit of the connection. SyncBackPro has excellent accountability over files processed with a good visual representation and good logging. It's a very nice piece of software. I like the "mirror" feature which will delete from and add to the destination as necessary to match the source.

The setup was so simple. I merely started an "everything" account for Amazon Cloud Drive. SyncBackPro took me to one-time Amazon authentication page, a key was exchanged, and that was it, with the least amount of interaction possible.

Amazon Cloud Drive "everything" costs $59.99 per year and according to customer support accepts up to 200 terabytes under this plan. I'm very glad I held out. This seems to be the best value for the money. SyncBackPro costs $54.95.

Comment: sadly SyncBackPro is only for Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while trying to sync a subfolder in Amazon Cloud Drive.  So here's how to enable local syncing for a subfolder already in Amazon Cloud Drive:

1. Right-click the Amazon Cloud Drive notification area ("tray") icon.
2. Right-click the vertical ... menu and select Preferences.
3. In the Sync tab, click Choose folders.
4. Put a checkmark next to any folder you want to sync.
5. Click Sync.
6. Click OK.

Comment: Please add information on which subdirectories are affected. When selecting a local location, the client creates a subdirectory "Amazon Drive" in it and syncs that location with the root location of the Amazon Drive account. A complete answer should reflect this.